# SSRS Schedules in an Agent Job - changing the delivery order?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-agent-job

We have a large number of reports that are setup as subscriptions linked to a schedule. The schedule is then executed as a step within a SQL Agent Job to make sure the reports are only run when certain other steps are first carried out.

When the reports are run from the SQL Agent, I was wondering if there was a way I could manage the priority of specific reports linked to the schedule so I can control which reports run next?

Comment: Are you using stored procs to trigger the reports? Something like [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3078/report-launcher-to-run-ssrs-report-subscriptions-on-demand/)?

Comment: We have a step setup in the Job that runs the following command:

Comment: EXECUTE sp_start_job '393F8B3E-AFAE-44A7-8928-985435AF3341'

Comment: where **393F8B3E...** is the ScheduleID

Comment: Correct me if I sound stupid; Can't you just place the statements in order of priority,so that they execute sequentially? `EXECUTE sp_start_job '1st sched id'; EXECUTE sp_start_job '2nd sched id' , and so on`

Comment: All the reports are linked to the same ScheduleID... So there is only 1 ScheduleID to initiate. I could go through the exercise of splitting the reports across different schedules but it seems over kill - especially if there is an option to update something like a LastRunDate field to alter which ones go next on request.

Comment: So do you have a single job dealing with the shared schedule or multiple jobs pertaining to the same schedule but multiple subscriptions?

Comment: There is just one single job that has a step that initiates many reports linked to one schedule.